# How can I get an army in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How can I have an Army in Skyrim? Is it possible to have one?
Also, is there any way to get a castle and be its ruler?

Comment: Are you talking about vanilla Skyrim? You could conceivably lead an army of followers with mods like [the Ultimate Follower Overhaul](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/14037).

Comment: This is not possible in Vanilla, as @Schism above said. If you are interested in mods I am sure there are a few that would potentially suit your needs.

Comment: "*is there any way to get a castle and be its ruler?*" [Yes, if you have the Dawnguard DLC.](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Volkihar_Keep) =)

Comment: Not sure why this got so many downvotes... perhaps you could offer some constructive criticism so that the asker my improve this question or future ones?

Comment: @Oktosite : There is no problem :) Perhaps who Voted down, know a lot about this feature and he/she thinks its a simple one. However, I Just want to get the Answer.

Comment: Don't understand the downvotes. It's a valid question. Maybe he simply has no experience with mods? The simple answer is no, but with modding the answer becomes an emphatic yes. I've detailed an answer below. Perhaps, OP, more information in future questions would be advisable. Include information on mods you may have tried (if any), DLC you have available/installed, or any other valid info we could use to help answer your question both promptly and accurately. Also, as mentioned in my answer, which version you are playing (PC/Console) is important for us to know as well.

Comment: @Jason this falls firmly into the category of, what I refer to in [this answer as "Stupid Thought Experiments."](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3198/can-i-do-x-questions/4482#4482)

Comment: Guess that's a matter of oppinion. If the question had been fleshed out with the information I suggested OP give in future questions, the answer would have been much more clear. If on consoles: No, if on PC, yes. It's quite simple. OP was clearly unfamiliar with modding, so I see nothing wrong with helping them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IMPORTANT: This answer assumes you are playing the PC version of Skyrim. Modding is not possible on any of the console versions and therefore the ultimate answer to your questions becomes an infallible NO.**

**Now, on with the answer:**

As mentioned in the comments above by several users, what you desire is impossible within vanilla Skyrim (official and unmodded).

For owening your own castle, galacticaninja, again in the above comments, mentioned a similar function within Dawnguard. I have not played this particular DLC and therefore cannot validate or deny that comment. This, though, is official DLC and would require no modding.

In terms of leading an "army," this is also impossible within vanilla Skyrim. You can have only one follower plus any quest related followers at any one time. This number does not generally get very high; rarely more than 2 including your permanent follower.

There is a way to get this functionality in Skyrim, though, and it involves some mods from the plethora available both online and within the Steam Workshop.

One particular mod of interest, [Ultimate Follower Overhaul](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/14037/?), has already been mentioned in the comments above and I suggest you look into that yourself. It completely overhauls the functionality of followers, allowing multiple followers as well as other useful changes (such as allowing followers to use any extra mounts to ride along with you). This would allow you to hire many followers and eventually turn them into a unit of cavalry, if you desired. It also allows you to better control their skills and equipment. There are also other, similar, mods that add less functionality to followers but still allow multiples. (EDIT: This mod raises the maximum follower limit to 15)

In terms of government, I would suggest this particular mod: "Become King of Riverhelm" found [here](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/16374/?) at Skyrim Nexus (one of the more frequented Skyrim modsites.) This adds an entirely new city to your Skyrim game and allows you to govern, defend, and upgrade both your keep and the surrounding city. You also collect the taxes and various revenues from the city. It's much more in depth then I'd like to explain here, but I suggest clicking the link and reading the full description on the mod's page.

There are many other great quality mods developed by the community that may suit your needs, and I suggest perusing them yourself sometime to see which better suit your style of play and your knowledge of modding.

Also, if you are unfamiliar with modding there are many tutorials and helpful mod managing programs to get you going, all found on [Skyrim Nexus](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/?), or with a Google search, if you aren't using Steam and its Workshop.

Comment: I'd also like to mention that many mods are also translated by other members of the community, and I know that Become King of Riverhelm is available in many languages other than the English version I linked within the answer.

Comment: Great Answer. Is it possible to use two mods at a time?

Comment: Absolutely. You can, technically, have as many mods as you want. There are two caveats to this though: 1) Performance. and 2) Compatibility. Mods that alter the same part of Skyrim aren't compatible as they override each-other. This can cause glitching and neither mod will function correctly. Multiple mods, large mods, or mods that raise the graphical quality of the game can all lower the framerate or cause other performance loss issues if your computer is not powerful enough to handle the increased load.

Comment: For installing UFO and Become King of Riverhelm, I have to install Skyrim: Nexux first, isn't it?

Comment: Skyrim Nexus is simply the name of the site where the community posts their mods for others to Download. Many of the modders will have instalation instructions within the description of their own mod and I would suggest following those, as they can differ slightly between each mod. There are programs that will do it for you automatically, or at least make it easier, and mods that recommend/require these programs will also mention them within their description. Skyrim Nexus does have it's own version of this type of program though, found [here](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/modmanager/?)